# Pandas Resample 5 mins data to Hourly average : Date issue

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time-series, timestamp

I am trying to resample a timeseries data from 5 min frequency to hourly average.

```
 df = pd.read_csv("my_data.csv", index_col=False, usecols=['A','B','C'])
```

output:

```
         A            B      C
0   16-01-21 0:00   95.75   0.0
1   16-01-21 0:05   90.10   0.0
2   16-01-21 0:10   86.26   0.0
3   16-01-21 0:15   92.72   0.0
4   16-01-21 0:20   81.54   0.0

df.A= pd.to_datetime(df.A)
```

Output:

```
             A            B      C
0   2021-01-16 00:00:00 95.75   0.0
1   2021-01-16 00:05:00 90.10   0.0
2   2021-01-16 00:10:00 86.26   0.0
3   2021-01-16 00:15:00 92.72   0.0
4   2021-01-16 00:20:00 81.54   0.0
```

Now I set the Timestamp column as index,

```
df.set_index('A', inplace=True)
```

And when I try to resample with

```
df2 = df.resample('H').mean()
```

I am getting this,

```
                       B         C
        A       
2021-01-02 00:00:00 79.970278   0.0
2021-01-02 01:00:00 77.951667   0.0
2021-01-02 02:00:00 77.610556   0.0
2021-01-02 03:00:00 80.800000   0.0
2021-01-02 04:00:00 84.305000   0.0
```

Was expecting this kind of timestamp with the average values for each hour,

```
       A             B         C
2021-01-16 00:00:00 79.970278   0.0
2021-01-16 01:00:00 77.951667   0.0
2021-01-16 02:00:00 77.610556   0.0
2021-01-16 03:00:00 80.800000   0.0
2021-01-16 04:00:00 84.305000   0.0
```

I am not sure where I am making a mistake. Help me out.

Comment: hej @Aswin, i don't see where your problem is. When I run your code for the dataframe you have given (5 rows), it correctly outputs one average = one row as all of the timestamps fall into one hour.

Comment: Hi @Per Joachim, thanks for your response. The output I am getting shows the date as 2nd January. But i actually have data from 16th January to 16th September.  I am expecting to get 24 rows for one day. With the average values.  for the expected values I put up there, i just changed the timestamp to reflect the dates from my original data set.

Comment: Hi @Corralien, The difference is the timestamps, I was expecting to get hourly averages for the 16th of January. But got 2nd of January.

Comment: hej @Aswin, when i run your code I see results for the correct timestamp. So maybe you should add the whole dataset so that we can reproduce the error

Comment: I think you need change `df.A= pd.to_datetime(df.A)` to `df.A= pd.to_datetime(df.A, dayfirst=True)`

Comment: @MrFuppes - you are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think problem here is some datetimes are wrongly converted:

```
#default is month first in df.A= pd.to_datetime(df.A)
01-02-21 -> 2021-01-02
```

Possible solutions:

```
df.A= pd.to_datetime(df.A, dayfirst=True)
```

Or:

```
df = pd.read_csv("my_data.csv", 
                 index_col=False, 
                 usecols=['A','B','C'], 
                 parse_dates=['A'], 
                 dayfirst=True)
```